# CMS which allows unregistered users to submit content

Tags: content-management-system, joomla

I am looking for a CMS- which would allow unregistered users to submit content.

From what I have read so far- that is not possible with Joomla . Is that correct ?

Open ID would be an OK compromise- but wouldn't want that either if I can help it - i.e they should be able to participate anonymously...

Comment: if joomla won't allow this, (and I don't know if it does or doesn't) then that is a BIG strike against joomla!

Comment: There are a lot of big strikes against Joomla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said what your requirements are, but the most popular (by number of users) CMS for unregistered users to submit content would surely be [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki).

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall if Joomla permits this. It's very easy to set up with a basic Drupal install, though.

Comment: this would have been my answer +1

Answer (score 1):

**Joomla does not** allow this functionality **out of the box**. You could add a 3rd party extension.